# HTML element btn is null, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is my JavaScript code, its job is to convert from numbers to numerals(the function works):

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
  const numbers = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
  const numeral = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];
  const arr = [];
  let renum = num;
  while (arr.reduce((before, after) => before + after, 0) < num) {
    const EL = numbers.findIndex(element => renum - element >= 0);
    arr.push(numbers[EL]);
    renum -= numbers[EL];
  }
  return arr.map(element => numeral[numbers.indexOf(element)]).join('');
}

let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => alert(convertToRoman(document.querySelector('input').value)), false);
```

And this is my html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title> Sumbit </title>
  </head>
  <body>       
  <script src="NBC.js"></script>
    <button class="btn"> Convert </button>
    <input type="number" class="inpu">
  </body>
</html>
```

So as you see, I want to make a button and an input field, when the user enters numbers and clicks on the button, `.value` gives the value as an argument to the function so when it clicks it(the event of click) it appears as an `alert` giving its roman numeral.

The problem is that it gives me 'btn is null` error in the console, when the code is executed, what's wrong?

I tried `document.getElementById(id)`, I tried removing "." of the class, I tried everything I could possible do.

Any solution?

Comment: At the time the script is loaded, the button doesn't exist yet. Move the script to the bottom, just before `</body>`, or use `DOMContentLoaded` event or some other way of deferring it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thank you! I was really about to give up. I'm sorry for this stupid question as this is my first practical test on DOM manipulation!

Comment: You could just move the script tag to be the last child of your HTML body, no extra code needed.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto it's ok, I try defer and it's perfectly working. Placing script on the end of the body seems like a bad idea to me, it makes the code very clustered unlike placing it on head alone.

Comment: It's your call Boy pro, defer has great support this days https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent accessing the [**`DOM`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) before it's fully loaded, add an event listener under the [**`DOMContentLoaded`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {...});
```

...and execute your code **within that event listener**:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sumbit</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="btn"> Convert </button>
  <input type="number" class="input" placeholder="Enter some numbers">
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      function convertToRoman(num) {
        const numbers = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
        const numeral = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];
        const arr = [];
        let renum = num;
        while (arr.reduce((before, after) => before + after, 0) < num) {
          const EL = numbers.findIndex(element => renum - element >= 0);
          arr.push(numbers[EL]);
          renum -= numbers[EL];
        }
        return arr.map(element => numeral[numbers.indexOf(element)]).join('');
      }

      let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => alert(convertToRoman(document.querySelector('input').value)), false);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also if you want the `DOM` to get parsed as fast as possible *(e.g. speeding up)* after the user has requested the page:

- [**make your JavaScript asynchronous**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)
- [**optimize loading of your CSS**](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery)

---

Also there was a **typo** in your HTML (`class="inpu"`):

```
<input type="number" class="inpu">
```

make sure to fix it:

```
<input type="number" class="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a job for `defer`, which will simply tell the browser to wait for the HTML-parser to finish before executing the script.

Explanation of the attribute:

> `<script defer>`
>
> defer downloads the file during HTML parsing and will only execute it
> after the parser has completed. defer scripts are also guaranteed to
> execute in the order that they appear in the document.

[Source](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html#script-defer)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20304658)

Comment: Included the explanation in question and link as a source rather than a resource.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do this, the first one is the listen for `DOMContentLoaded` event listener on the `document` object.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');  
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => alert(convertToRoman(document.querySelector('input').value)), false);
});
```

the second method is to use either the `async` or `defer` attribute on the script element. if you use the `async` attribute loading of the script won't block the `DOM` from loading , if you use the `defer` attribute the script element must load it's `src` value before the `DOM` will be loaded

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Sumbit </title>
    </head>
    <body>       
        <script src="NBC.js" async></script>
        <button class="btn"> Convert </button>
        <input type="number" class="inpu">
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is just a side note, is either you put the script element as the last child of the `body` element or put it inside the head element